# coffeeScript. Как вызвать метод, не указывая скобки?

Tags: coffeescript

```
Object::pr = -> 
   console.log eval("'"+@+"'").toString()
   console.log '____________________________'
   @
# 'hello.coffee'.pr()

Object::classGet = -> 
  this.constructor.name.toString()
```

Есть метод classGet().

Он вызывается вот так.

```
[].classGet().pr()
```

И он вызывается вот так.

```
(do [].classGet).pr()
```

А как переписать метод classGet, чтобы вызвать его вот так

```
[].classGet.pr()
```

или вот так

```
[].classGet.pr
```

Comment: С некоторыми особенностями языка приходится мириться и если он требует на функцию вызывать скобки, то ничего с этим не поделаешь. Это можно было бы попытаться сделать через get/set на свойство, но не для уже существующего класса без возможности переопределения и было бы крайне неэффективным решением.

Comment: Пожалуйста, прокомментируйте вот такое `     Object::pr = -> 
 console.log eval("'"+@+"'").toString()
 console.log '____________________________'
 @

stringCreate=(s)->
  new String s

Function::property = (prop, desc) ->
  Object.defineProperty @prototype, prop, desc

class String
  constructor: (@s) ->
  @property 'classGet',
    get: -> @s.constructor.name.toString()

stringCreate('').classGet.pr() `